# TFS 2013 on windows server 2012 R2 and Analysis Services error: TF400069

Tags: tfs, installation, sql-server-2012, ssas, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two machines: one is the host and the other is the Hyper-v VM. Both have Windows Server 2012 R2 installed.

I installed the domain controller and SQL Server 2012 SP1 with CU7 and SharePoint 2010 on the host. I installed SharePoint 2013 on the VM, and I want to install TFS 2013 in Advanced Configuration (I logged in as Administrator to VM Machine). It seemed to work, but when I click on the Test button in the Analysis Services Section the Wizard gave me this error:

> TF400069: You must install either SQL Server Analysis Services version
>   11.0 or the SQL Server Client Tools on the application tier to ensure that the Analysis Services object model is present for warehouse
>   processing.  Once you have installed the necessary components, rerun
>   the readiness checks.

I installed both Analysis Services and Client Tools, and Analysis Services works just fine. And I can Access it via Management Studio and change its properties. I also Disabled the Firewall on both Machines.

I googled and find nothing related. What else can I try?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are three types of Analysis Services installations: multidimensional, tabular, and SharePoint integrated. You can only install one of these types per instance. Maybe you selected the wrong type?

Comment: @FrankPI: As far as i know it must be "multidimensional" and i installed so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In next paragraph of my question just after the error message i mentioned that i installed both Analysis Services and Client Tools, but what i didn't mentioned was i didn't install neither of them on VM Machine which is my TFS on it.
So i think we all get it now and that is i should have installed one of Analysis Services or Client Tools on the VM Machine where my TFS 2013 going to Configure.